# How would I create a shadowy "Fog of War" effect in Game Maker Studio 2?

Tags: rendering, game-maker, fog-of-war

You know if you ever played "StarCraft," as you explore the map it's dark until you go to that area. I am trying to replicate this effect in Gamemaker studio 2.

I want to create a shadowed area effect on the map, so that when a "obj_player" moves to a darkened area it reveals that part of the map.

Here is a picture to help describe the effect i'm trying to achieve:

[image: Image of fog of war in StarCraft II]

Comment: This is called "Fog of War" - did you try [searching for existing guides on how to achieve this in Game Maker](https://www.google.com/search?q=game-maker+fog-of-war)?

Comment: not really because what I was searching did not get me anywhere an answer or some links to some guides would be helpful

Comment: How far did you get with the links provided above?

Comment: @sketcherskt try searching "Fog of war in Game Maker" online, and try some tutorials. If you get stuck on a specific step, update this question (or make a new one) with all the details. This way, it would be easier for someone here to spot where you are having problems.